# Time conversion to HH:MM PM/AM format

Tags: jquery, json, datetime

Using a Json data where Time is coming up as String.

```
{"startTime": "08:00:00","sessionId": 231,"endTime": "13:00:00"},
```

Need to convert this in my Jsp as below format StartTime is **8:00 AM** and End time is **1:00 PM**. Is their a way to achieve this in Jquery or Javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

If jsp, you can try `<fmt:formatDate>` tag of JSTL.  There are many examples around.  If jQuery/javascript, you can use [jquery-dateFormat](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use [dateJs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the download link on date.js points to an old out-of-date version. You need to get the new one by checking out the repository.